# No version number on GWT 2.7

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I'm trying to add the GWT 2.7 SDK to my eclipse workspace but I'm not getting a version number in the install and it's causing problems. I've installed it manually (as it doesn't seem to be in the update list) and I don't see any option to set a version number.

I've downloaded from http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html .

I've installed it through windows > preferences > google < web toolkit > add.

Any ideas?

[image: gwt]

Comment: Are you using an older version of the GWT plugin?

Comment: I believe my version is up to date.

Comment: I got this error when working with older versions of the gwt plugin. I checked my installation. Mars with the latest plugin works fine and shows the version number.

Comment: I'm not sure whats going on. I'd try out the latest version here which is also has latest SDK, GWT Plugin for Eclipse (or GPE fork). http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/Download.html